# How to convert CSV to Json in proper format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, flask

Hi I am new to csv conversion to Json using python. 
I am trying to convert a csv file to json format and return the response in a function call but getting slash characters.

When i open CSV File using the **Notepad++** this is how the data looks

```
"Sno ","Name","Age ","City"
"1","Alex","27","Newyork"
"2","Smith","25","Los angeles"
"3","austin","26","Calfornia
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
    {
        "Sno ": "1",
        "Name": "Alex",
        "Age ": "27",
        "City": "Newyork"
    },
    {
        "Sno ": "2",
        "Name": "Smith",
        "Age ": "25",
        "City": "Los angeles"
    },
    {
        "Sno ": "3",
        "Name": "austin",
        "Age ": "26",
        "City": "Calfornia"
    }
]
```

**Python code:**

```
def refresh():
    # reading the header from the csv file in an array
    with open(r"C:\Users\prasanna.kommuri\example_flask_application\target_py_files\data_file.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        csv_header_row = next(reader)

    #Reading the content from the csv file
    json_data = [json.dumps(d) for d in csv.DictReader(open(r"C:\Users\prasanna.kommuri\example_flask_application\target_py_files\data_file.csv", 'r'), fieldnames=csv_header_row, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)]
    return jsonify(json_data)
```

**Actual output:**

```
[
   "{\"Sno \": \"Sno \", \"Name\": \"Name\", \"Age \": \"Age \", \"City\": \"City\"}",
   "{\"Sno \": \"1\", \"Name\": \"Alex\", \"Age \": \"27\", \"City\": \"Newyork\"}",
   "{\"Sno \": \"2\", \"Name\": \"Smith\", \"Age \": \"25\", \"City\": \"Los angeles\"}",
   "{\"Sno \": \"3\", \"Name\": \"austin\", \"Age \": \"26\", \"City\": \"Calfornia\"}"
]
```

Can someone please help where i am going wrong or any **suggestions/responses** would be helpful
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your output is fine as it represents the string value of your json. Do you want JSON or just a dict? try [d for d in csv.DictReader....] and see if you get the output you desire

Comment: Thanks @Kristian that helped !

Answer (score 1):

```
import json, csv

with open(r'U:\foobar.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    print(json.dumps(list(csv.DictReader(f)), indent=4))
```

prints

```
[
    {
        "Sno ": "1",
        "Name": "Alex",
        "Age ": "27",
        "City": "Newyork"
    },
    {
        "Sno ": "2",
        "Name": "Smith",
        "Age ": "25",
        "City": "Los angeles"
    },
    {
        "Sno ": "3",
        "Name": "austin",
        "Age ": "26",
        "City": "Calfornia"
    }
]
```

or to output to file

```
with open(r'U:\foobar.csv', 'r', newline='') as fin:
    with open(r'U:\foobar.json', 'w') as fout:
        json.dump(list(csv.DictReader(f)), fout, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
import csv
import json

def refresh():
    # reading the header from the csv file in an array
    data_dict_list = []
    with open(r"result.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        csv_header_row = next(reader)

        for data in reader:
            data_dict_list.append(
                {
                    csv_header_row[0]: data[0],
                    csv_header_row[1]: data[1],
                    csv_header_row[2]: data[2],
                    csv_header_row[3]: data[3],
                 }
            )

        return  json.dumps(data_dict_list, indent=4)

result = refresh()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "Sno ": "1",
        "Name": "Alex",
        "Age ": "27",
        "City": "Newyork"
    },
    {
        "Sno ": "2",
        "Name": "Smith",
        "Age ": "25",
        "City": "Los angeles"
    },
    {
        "Sno ": "3",
        "Name": "austin",
        "Age ": "26",
        "City": "Calfornia"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** this is not explaining why your code is failing, but is giving an alternative solution using `pandas`, as you mentioned you were open to new solutions as well.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO  # that's just to pretend I have a .csv file like yours

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''"Sno ","Name","Age ","City" 
"1","Alex","27","Newyork" 
"2","Smith","25","Los angeles" 
"3","austin","26","Calfornia"'''))                                                                                                                 

>>> print(df.to_json(orient="records", indent=4))                                                                                                                      
[
    {
        "Sno ":1,
        "Name":"Alex",
        "Age ":27,
        "City ":"Newyork "
    },
    {
        "Sno ":2,
        "Name":"Smith",
        "Age ":25,
        "City ":"Los angeles "
    },
    {
        "Sno ":3,
        "Name":"austin",
        "Age ":26,
        "City ":"Calfornia"
    }
]
```

So in a nutshell, assuming you have a path leading to your .csv file called `path_to_csv`, it's a 1-liner:

```
json_data = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv).to_json(orient="records", indent=4)
```